# (icloud photo sharing) Two phones, two cameras... one unified place to upload?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, sharing, family-sharing

all I want is for photos from my wife's iPhone and my iPhone to background upload to the same place?

My preference is to stay within Apple's ecosystem, but I will happily consider anything reliable.  My impression is that Google Photos, Carousel/Dropbox, OneDrive, etc. are flakey with automatic background uploading, but I would love to be corrected on that impression.

Sharing the same AppleID isn't optimal for a variety of reasons.  I think my primary beef here is limitations with iCloud Drive and Family Sharing both still feeling like beta features, but photos is really where it hits me.  Even if I could just assign Photos to something other than the primary AppleID on the phone, that would do it.

Similar questions have been asked, but not for a while (certainly not since ios9 that I have seen-- I did look), and I don't think they are exactly the same.  That said, it blows my mind that this isn't easy, so maybe I am just being stubborn.  I can't be the only person who thinks this should be easy, can I?